# Add marker in multiple position dynamically in Google Map

Tags: android

I want to make an android app which will show logged users position based on their longitude and latitude dynamically. Dynamically means, I will never fix the number of user for map marker. the number of users can be varied. And user information will store into firebase database from where app calculates the number of current users and will show them on the google map with the marker.  How can I do this ??

Comment: No sir, actually if you ever work with google map in android then you must know that there is a method known as 'googleMap.addMarker(options)' and options is the object of MarkerOptions class and options take longitude, latitude for only one at a time.  My question was how I used this to add multiple users position dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Store users' longitude and latitude in session object.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("longitude", longitude);
session.setAttribute("latitude", latitude);
```

In Admin mode of your application, You can access all active sessions.

Use HttpSessionActivationListener to find all active sessions,

```
class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionActivationListener
{

    public static final Map activeSessions = HashMap<String,
    HttpSession>();

public void sessionDidActivate(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    activeSessions.put(session.getId(), session);
}

public void sessionWillPassivate(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    activeSessions.remove(session.getId();
}

}
```

Define the above listener in web.xml as,

```
<listener>
<listener-class>my.package.SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Use below code to get the active sessions,

```
SessionCounterListener.activeSessions.size(); // Returns the number of active sessions.

SessionCounterListener.activeSessions.getValues(); // Returns the all the active sessions.
```

Traverse through all the active session and store longitude and latitude.

**Code to show multiple markers**

```
ArrayList<MarkerData> markersArray = new ArrayList<MarkerData>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < markersArray.size() ; i++ ) {

    createMarker(markersArray.get(i).getLatitude(), markersArray.get(i).getLongitude(), markersArray.get(i).getTitle(), markersArray.get(i).getSnippet(), markersArray.get(i).getIconResID());
}

...

protected Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, int iconResID) {

    return googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .title(title)
        .snippet(snippet);
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResID)));
```

}